# Массивы в объектах js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Существует объект, в котором в значениях лежат массивы с данными. Хочу, чтобы 1 массив ( priceCard ) собрал значения из других массивов с данными.

```
let newObj={
    price: [13400, 500, 600],
    man : ["Andrey", "Ivan"],
    priceCard: [{name: "Alex", cash: 1}]
};
```

Можно ли обратиться, допустим, к `newObj.price[1]` из `newObj.priceCard[0].cash`? Чтобы в `priceCard` лежало значение = `500`? Или как это сделать?

Comment: cash: 1 - 1 - это индекс элемента из price?
name: "Alex" -
name берется из man c индексом cash? Опиши подробнее, что с чем связано. Обратиться можно, вопрос - как.

Comment: Исправлюсь, есть priceCard : [
   name: " ",
   cash: " "
]
Как сослаться к двум другим массивам , чтобы вытащить у них значения?
priceCard : [
   name: "~тут ссылка на массив man со значением Ivan, допустим~",
   cash: "~тут ссылка на массив price со значением 500, допустим~ "
] вот так хочу сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let newObj={
    price: [13400, 500, 600],
    man : ["Andrey", "Ivan"],
    get priceCard() {
      return [{name: this.man[1], cash: this.price[1]}];
    }
};  

console.log(newObj.priceCard);
```

Comment: Тю, точно, через метод, совсем из головы выпало (большой код был)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```html
//тогда решение: 
newObj.priceCard.name = newObj.man;
newObj.priceCard.cash= newObj.price;

//Итог:
priceCard:{
  name: ["Andrey", "Ivan"],
  cash: [13400, 500, 600]
}
```